# Connect to MySQL table using PHP (XAMPP)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, xampp

I am trying to make a CRUD in PHP. Apache and MySQL is still running.

```
class DB
{
    static private $connection;
    const DB_TYPE = "mysql";
    const DB_HOST = "localhost";
    const DB_NAME = "crud";
    const USER_NAME = "root";
    const USER_PASSWORD = "";

    static public function getConnection()
    {
        if (static::$connection == null) {
            try {
                static::$connection =  new PDO(self::DB_TYPE . "host" . self::DB_HOST . "dbname" . self::DB_NAME . self::USER_NAME . self::USER_PASSWORD);
            } catch (Exception $exception) {
                throw new Exception("connection failed");
            }
        }
        return static::$connection;
    }
}
```

I am running on `localhost:3306`

phpMyAdmin is up and running

The output is in the picture

output:

[image]

Comment: Your error is text. In future please paste it as text! There's no need for a picture of text. This is mentioned in [ask]. Thankyou.

Comment: Anyway, you don't know what the problem is because you've hidden the real error with your fake Exception. That is a design flaw. Try `catch (Exception $exception) {
              echo $exception->getMessage();
              exit();
            }` instead, then you can see _why_ the connection failed. Or you could log it to a file instead, if you prefer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PDO invocation looks weird.

```
static::$connection =  new PDO(self::DB_TYPE . "host" . self::DB_HOST . "dbname" . self::DB_NAME . self::USER_NAME . self::USER_PASSWORD);
```

The construct for this is `new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);`

The dsn has this format:

```
mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1;port=3333 then , user then , password
```

Your dsn section seems wrong, it should be more like this:

```
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname='. self::DB_NAME .';host=' . self::DB_HOST ;
$user = self::USER_NAME;
$password = self::USER_PASSWORD;

$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This solves my problem.

Answer (score -1):

I think you forgot spaces and signs in your connection arguments

That is your syntax :

```
new PDO(self::DB_TYPE . "host" . self::DB_HOST . "dbname" . self::DB_NAME . self::USER_NAME . self::USER_PASSWORD);
```

Which give :

```
"mysqlhostlocalhostdbnamecrudroot"
```

This is the syntax from the doc :

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
```